# double translation in symfony2

Tags: symfony, translation, twig

I try to use a simple validator translation.
my files:

validation.yml:

```
Some\UserBundle\Entity\Address:
    properties:
        name:
            - MaxLength:  {limit: 2, message: "some_user.max_length" }
```

and validators.pl.yml:

```
some_user:
    max_length: Wartość jest zbyt długa
```

in twig file loaded by ajax, I have this:

```
{{ form_error(form) }}
```

When I try my validator, app throw this:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to choose a translation for "Wartość jest zbyt długa" with locale "pl".")
```

It seems like double translation? Any ideas?

I found workaround, in Action:

```
$errorList = $this->get('validator')->validate($address);
$errors = "";
if (count($errorList) > 0) {
    foreach ($errorList as $err) {
        $errors.= $this->get('translator')
                    ->trans($err->getMessage(), array(), 'validators') . "\n";
    }

}
```

but its awful way, I think.

It seems like translated twice in twig... but why?

Answer (score 3):

it was problem with "pluralization"

validators.pl.yml should look like this:

```
Some\UserBundle\Entity\Address:
properties:
    name:
        - MaxLength:  {limit: 2, message: "some_user.max_length|some_user.max_length_s" }
```

but now, twig render only:

```
<ul><li>some_user.max_length_s</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a long time ago since you asked the question but I just came across the same problem so hopefully that would be usefull for others:

Your **validators.pl.yml** should look like:

```
Some\UserBundle\Entity\Address:
properties:
    name:
        - MaxLength:  {limit: 2, message: "some_user.max_length" }
```

Then your file that manages the translation, let's say **validators.pl.xliff** should look like:

```
...

<trans-unit id="1">
    <source>some_user.max_length</source>
    <target>Your text|Your plural text</target>
</trans-unit>

...
```

And the result in twig will now be rendered correctly.

Comment: `Core\HardwareBundle\Entity\WarningConfig:
      properties:
          name:
              - NotBlank: ~
              - MinLength: { limit: 5, message:  "single|plural" }`

Still doesn't work for me - getting the "Unable to choose a translation for..." exception. Symfony 2.1.4

Answer (score 1):

You should check `PluralizationRules.php` to see how pluralization is defined for your language. According to [unicode](http://unicode.org/cldr/charts/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#pl) you should supply 3 transaltion options, not 2. Because you  supplyed 2 and the data needed the third an exception was thrown (the `InvalidArgumentException`). I find the exception message a bit missleading :)